# Excel VBA Copy Cell to another sheet while keeping Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post, complete newbie. I have gotten so far by browsing thru this forum. I would be glad if you could provide me with comments to improve that code and make it do what I would like it to do.

I would like to program actions using Excel VBA to do the following: Upon clicking a button, the code would randomly choose a value from a sheet, combine it with a value from an adjacent cell and copy it to another sheet while preserving the hyperlink attached to the first value.
This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim ExNo As Range
   Dim Exercise As Range
   Dim CurrentCell As Range
   Dim RandTemp As Single
   Dim NbEx As Single

Set ExNo = Worksheets("ExList").Range("B3", "B100")
Set Exercise = Worksheets("ExList").Range("C3", "C100")
NbEx = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("ExList").Range("B3", "B100"))
For i = 1 To 5    
    RandTemp = Rnd()            
    Set CurrentCell = Worksheets("Exercise").Cells(4 * i, 2)
    CurrentCell = WorksheetFunction.Index(ExNo, Int(NbEx * RandTemp) + 1) & "  " & WorksheetFunction.Index(Exercise, Int(NbEx * RandTemp) + 1)

Next

With ActiveSheet
   .Shapes("CommandButton1").Top = .Range("B25").Top + 4
   .Shapes("CommandButton1").Left = .Range("B25").Left + 4
   .Shapes("CommandButton1").Width = .Range("B25").Width + .Range("C25").Width - 8
.Shapes("CommandButton1").Height = .Range("B25").Height + .Range("B26").Height - 8

End With

End Sub
```

The values are correctly copied but the hyperlinks are not carried over. 
Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line that gets the value of the hyperlink from the cell-

```
sHyperVal = CurrentCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

Then when pasting the two values together use something similar to the following-

```
CurrentCell = "=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(""" & sHyperVal & """, """ & firstVal & " " & secondVal & """),"""")"
```

That should give you the desired results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it work perfectly. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.